# Angular parameter routing not working as external link

Tags: angular

i have an angular 8 project with a route like  http://example.com/tutorial/css where "css" is a parameter. if I click on it from a link from my project it works but if i share it as a link it is not found (404). It seems that  "css" is added to the navigation route at this time. I would be glad if i find help

the code below shows how i get my route parameter

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
    this.pid = params.get("param");
    console.log(this.pid);
  })
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. So you have a problem with loading a route but you haven't given any details that could help with understanding why the problem is occurring. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. It is also likely that this is a problem with how you're hosting the app rather than the app itself. It would be helpful if you share those details if you think they're relevant.

Comment: thank you @KurtHamilton i think it s the way its been hosted because it works well on local host. sorry about the clarity of my question.

Comment: Quick question, does it happen for other routes or just for this one? Usual solution is to let server serve index.html for every requested route and then let Angular handle the routing